# Is constant current achievable with a dc/dc converter?

Tags: capacitor, dc-dc-converter

I'm an electronics novice and part of a rocketry club. During the 4th of July we try to do a mass launch of rockets. Doesn't always work. I thought about building a capacitive discharge circuit to launch about 50 rockets and wow the spectators. The line of rockets would span about 100 feet using 22 gauge copper wire. I'd probably be another 100 feet away. For this much resistance I'm thinking I need a good amount of voltage.

So, each rocket requires an "electric match" to electrically fire. The electric match basically looks like a matchbook match head with wire leads. Each match requires 1 amp to pop and produce flame, per specs.

I purchased some photoflash capacitors, a toggle switch, a 12v battery and started to think about how I would charge the capacitor and looked into dc/dc converters. But most produced low watts. A 12v to 100v converter had a 1.5w spec. To my understanding that would only produce .015 amps. Somewhat expensive as well.

I need some insight on how I can get this to work. Would I need a dc/dc booster with a constant current of 1 amp?

Comment: This might be interesting to you: http://www.pyroinnovations.com/ematches.html

Answer (score 4):

The idea behind the capacitive discharge circuit is that you can charge it as slowly as you like, and then release it all quickly when needed. The current capability of the supply doesn't affect how the starters are ignited, it just affects how long it takes to recharge before the next launch.

The way this works is, your power supply can provide 15 mA for several seconds (or even minutes) to charge up the capacitors. The capacitors charge according to the formula

\$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t} = I/C\$

When charged, the stored energy in the capacitor is

\$ E = \dfrac{1}{2}CV^2\$

This energy is what you will use to heat up your igniters.

Then you disconnect the supply and close a switch to connect the capacitor to the igniter, and the capacitors can release its energy quickly into the igniter. The power supply isn't involved at all during the time when the igniters are being powered.

One thing to watch out for is, if the power supply is vastly underpowered, it will be spending a long time at the beginning of the charging cycle driving a much lower voltage than it is designed for (while the capacitor voltage is ramping up from 0 to near the inal value). Depending how the supply is designed, it might not last long when used this way.

Answer (score 1):

I hear that a commercial electric match typically has a resistance of about 1.5 Ohm and a recommended firing current around 1 Ampere.
([Alan Yates. "Electrical Ignition".](http://www.vk2zay.net/article/14)) ([Pyromate: Basics of Electric Firing.](http://www.pyromate.com/Basics-of-Electrical-Firing.htm)) ([Wikipedia: electric match.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/electric_match))
In other words, it (briefly) requires about 1.5 Watt per match to fire.
Since you want to launch 50 rockets at once, you need about 75 W of power.
A single automobile battery can easily supply several times this amount of power
for a minute.

It sounds like the setup have about 200 feet on the map of copper pair, so the total distance is 400 foot (out and back).

22 AWG copper wire has a resistance of about 16 Ohm per 1000 foot.
So 400 foot has a resistance of 6.4 Ohms.

As you have already discovered, simply applying the 12 V battery to a bunch of electric matches doesn't work.
By the often misunderstood [maximum power transfer theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/maximum_power_transfer_theorem),
the maximum power you can extract at the far end of a 6.4 Ohm resistance connected only to a 12 V battery is about 11.25 W.
So at 1.5 W per electric match, you can light at most 11.25 W / 1.5 W => 7 electric matches with this simple 12 V system.

To light 50 rockets requires a higher voltage, higher current, less lead-wire resistance, matches that require less power, or some combination.

So what is [the simplest thing that could possibly work](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoTheSimplestThingThatCouldPossiblyWork)?

A big storage capacitor slowly charged up from 1 battery using some kind of DC-DC converter, and then quickly discharged into the electric matches, would work, as described by Alan Yates and The Photon. The system would weight much less than 4 batteries.

It may be simpler to use a few batteries of 12 V each
(perhaps borrow automobile batteries).
There are many arrangements that would work:

- Wiring all the matches in series, in a big loop, the entire loop would (briefly) run at 1 A. The total resistance of the loop is about 50 * 1.5 Ohm for the matches + 6.4 Ohm for the wiring = 81 Ohms. To drive 1 A through this resistance requires about 7 batteries (12 V each) in series. ( I*R = 1 A * 81 Ohm = 81 V )
- Wiring matches in chains of 10 matches per chain, then connecting all the chains in parallel, requires 5 chains at 1 A each, which would (briefly) pull 5 A from the battery. The total resistance of the loop is about 6.4 Ohm for the wiring + 1.5 Ohm * 10 / 5 = 9.4 Ohms. To drive 5 A through this resistance requires about 4 batteries (12 V each) in series. ( I*R = 5 A * 9.4 Ohm = 47 V ).

As [others have already pointed](http://www.pyroinnovations.com/fireworkstraining_electricity101.html) out,
"matches wired in series-parellel combinations can fire more electric matches than series or parallel alone".

I see that [Robert Briody](https://www.publicmissiles.com/images/IgnitersWhitePaperbyG-Wiz.pdf) has measured a surprisingly wide variation in the electrical characteristics of electric matches.

Comment: In my experience wiring them in series is unreliable; they go open and some in the series will not have heated up enough yet.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: I hear that it varies from manufacturer to manufacturer -- someone at [Pyrotechnic Innovations](http://www.pyroinnovations.com/fireworkstraining_electricity101.html) says: "From personal experience, I have seen certain electric match brands work flawlessly, and others fail when in series on a regular basis."